# If $p$ is a prime number, prove that there exist infinitely many whole numbers $n$, such that $p$ divides $n \cdot 2^n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $n$ be an integer.
If $p$ divides $n \cdot 2^n+1$ we get $n \cdot 2^n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ or $n \cdot 2^n \equiv p-1 \pmod p $. Now if we let $n=p-1$

$(p-1)2^{\varphi(p)} \equiv p-1 \pmod p$, because $2^{\varphi(p)} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. So $n=p-1$ is one solution, how do I prove there are infinitely many?

Comment: if $p=2$ then $p \not | ( n2^n +1)$ for any $n$. You need $p$ to be an odd prime.

Comment: Yeah, its because $gcd(2,p)=1$, right. If not $2^{\varphi(p)} \equiv 1 \mod p$ doesnt work.

Comment: $n \cdot 2^n+1$ is always an odd number, so it can't be divisible by 2.

Comment: Ohh, also that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually $p$ needs to be odd.

Now, as you said, if $k \equiv 0 \mod{p-1}$ we have $2^k \equiv 1 \mod p$.
We can therefore choose $k$ such that $k \equiv 0 \mod{p-1}$ and $k \equiv -1 \mod{p}$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Maybe, but don't think i can.

Comment: @Bobcat Do you know the chinese remainder theorem ?